# When are new blocks transmitted between nodes?

Tags: graph, graph-theory, blockchain

Let's say node A creates a new block, and sends it to it's peers, like in the image below.

[image]

B, C, and D agree that it is a valid block and they add it to their chains.

However, how will the peers of B, C, and D know about the new block? Let's say D has peers E and F. Will E and F need to wait until D creates a new block, and sends this block together with the block from A. Or, will D inform E and F about the new block from A once it has been verified?

[image]

Comment: I think it's a protocol specific question, and have nothing to do with graph or it's theories. Sounds like publish-subscriber design pattern vs ....

Answer (score 2):

In bitcoin P2P network, once a block is mined, and propagated to peers (B, C, D), they validate it via several criteria, which include -

1. checking that the block's header is valid and has a hash of previous block on blockchain
2. validate transactions inside the block
3. check that the block was mined properly according to current difficulty rate
   and some more

If all those validations pass, then the block is added to B's, C's and D's local blockchain, and propagated immediately to their peers, so that it'll get added to their blockchain image as well.

This way, when a new block is mined, it propagates to the whole bitcoin network in few seconds.